# How to use the cut command together with w to produce a list of login names and CPU times corresponding to each active Process?

Tags: linux

Can you use the cut command together with w to produce a list of login names and CPU times corresponding to each active process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
ps au | tail -n +2 | awk '{ u[$1] += $3 } END { for (x in u) print(x, u[x]) }'
```

It sums the third column of `ps`which on my system is %CPU for each user (first column).

Comment: Thanks for the information pretty close to what I am trying to get but im missing the active process.